# Is there a famo.us offline version

Tags: javascript, cdn, famo.us

In all examples for [famo.us](http://famo.us) the required scripts are loaded directly from the famo.us website.

The download link at the top right of the homepage gives you an example for a boilerplate, which also contains the download of the required files from the cdn.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/lib/require.js"></script>
...
```

There is no download for the needed includes on the site.

Is there a way to program an offline version of your apps?

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is valid but might be better worded as "Is there a download of the Famo.us javascript library in it's entirety?"

As of this Answer, there is not a download of the library unless you download it yourself from the cdn links. This is feasible and would work fine.  But that is not the purpose of how you should probably use the library except for doing a proof or example.

The intention of the library is to create a leaner build by using the scaffold project created by the Yeoman generator [generator-famous](https://github.com/Famous/generator-famous) to scaffold a [grunt and bower project](https://github.com/Famous/famous#installation). OR Another package to create the leanest project build for your application.

Here are some options:

- [Famous Tools Dist Generator](https://github.com/FamousTools/famous-dist-generator) (Tools to create a local copy in different builds)
- [Famous Seed](https://github.com/Famous/famous-seed) (Create local project using the generator)
- [Browserify Seed](https://github.com/Famous/browserify-seed)
- [Webpack Seed](https://github.com/talves/famous-webpack-seed) (Not official, but in review by Famo.us)

Answer (score 0):

They are working on that, but it might take a few weeks.
Your best bet is to simply install all needed resources and generate the sample project yourself. This takes about 2 minutes of your time and you will have the source code of all resources available.

Here is a step by step guide: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-famous

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there is no a downloadable package that allow you to work with project relative links. But it is simple to achieve, just navigate to the link "http://code.famo.us/lib/require.js copy the code, place it into your javascript usual folder and you can work offline with it by having the src attribute pointing to that file. You also need to have the style sheet or your tests will not be visualised as you expect.